# Mediawiki nginx 500 internal server error

Tags: php, nginx, mediawiki

I'm trying to set up mediawiki and I keep getting a 500 internal server error.

`/var/log/nginx/error.log` is empty. PHP errors are logged there, but I don't see any errors relating to mediawiki.

I've tried setting `display_errors` and `display_startup_errors` to on in php.ini, but that hasn't helped.

I thought it could be a file permissions thing, but the entire of /wiki is set to 755 and owned by `www-data:www-data`.

I've also followed this: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:How_to_debug and included the relevant lines in `/wiki/index.php` and `/wiki/LocalSettings.php` but the error log still remains empty.

This is my nginx config:

```
server_tokens off;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

server {
        listen 443;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/certs/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/certs/privkey.pem;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.php;

        server_name example.com;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        error_page 500 /500.html;

        location = /wiki {
         return 301 /wiki/;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
         include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
         fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
         fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
         include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
        }
}
```

How do I fix this? I can't figure out exactly what's wrong if there's nothing in the error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by removing `fastcgi_intercept_errors on;` which resulted in mediawiki stating that I was missing the `xml` PHP extension.